# Programmatically prevent USB file system pop-up when plugging in USB via OTG cable connected to Android device

Tags: java, android, popup, usb-otg

I'm creating an Android app to access a file system of a USB mass storage drive via an USB-OTG cable.

When I attach the drive via cable, the file system pops up automatically.

Is there any way I can programmatically prevent this?

Comment: Have you found any answer?